# Population with known distribution (not normal) versus small sample

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, bootstrap

I have a complete population consisting of 6587 individuals (genes) and for each individual I have a distance value. These distance values are not normally distributed.

I'm interested in determining if a sample of 348 individuals (which has a smaller mean distance value compared with the mean distance value from the complete population) is significantly different than expected.

I have limited statistics background and would appreciate advice on what statistical test to use.

Ideas include:

1. two sample t-test (probably not right, since its not a normal distribution)
2. wilcoxon rank sum test (buddy suggested this)
3. some other test that's easy to implement in R
4. custom test - one idea I had was to randomly pick out 348 individuals (with replacement) and determine their mean distance. Then repeat this 1000 times (I think this is called bootstrapping). I did this, and I get a normal distribution of values with mean 32000 (same as population mean ) and sd = 2000. The mean distance value for the actual sample of 348 individuals was 18000. So by 1-tail p-value from normal distribution of mean 32000 and sd=2000 this appears significant.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to take you at your word that the population really is a population in the right sense.

> I'm more interested in comparing the mean of the smaller sample with the mean of the total population.

If you know the distribution of the total population, you know its mean. So you're in the position of trying to compare a sample mean to a population mean. Your sample is of size 348. This is a *one sample* test, not a two sample.

Points (corresponding to your numbering):

1) The CLT should give you approximate normality of the sample mean, unless the distribution is pretty extreme (heavily skewed, for example -- you can check the approximate normality of the distribution of the sample mean in several ways); by the same token, you should be able to ignore the uncertainty in the standard deviation. You don't need to worry about whether the one sample t-statistic has a t-distribution because a one sample z-statistic (basically the same quantity but taking $s$ to be $\sigma$) should be very close to a z-distribution.

2) The relevant rank test is not a Wilcoxon rank-sum test because you know the population. The one-sample equivalent is a Wilcoxon signed-rank test, but that assumes symmetry; it's also not testing the mean, but a slightly different measure of location. If you don't have near symmetry the obvious rank based one sample test would be the sign test, which is also not testing the mean. *IF* you consider only shift alternatives and you assume the only difference between sample and population is that possible shift, you could test against the population equivalent of the locations that they do test for, and if they're different, by direct implication the means differ by the same amount. In the case of the sign test, that would mean testing against the population median in order to also test for a difference in means. However, I suspect that the required assumption of identical shapes apart from location shift is not likely to be tenable - let me know if you think shift-only alternatives make sense.

4) Resampling approaches (either using randomization or bootstrapping) are possible.

Lets discuss some randomization tests:

a) If you could assume symmetry, a test immediately suggests itself, based on the same randomization idea that the Wilcoxon signed rank test uses, but based on the data, not the ranks - that is you take away the population mean from the sample values, count how many + and - signs there are, and randomly reassign the signs to those differences to get the randomization distribution.

b) You could randomly sample 348 values from the whole (6857+348) combined sample-plus-other-population and calculate the distribution of means, comparing your mean with that distribution (I'd lean toward this).

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks for the thorough response.  I like the 4B approach and want to make sure I have the logic correct.  For the organism I'm studying, there are 6587 known genes and I have a distance value for each gene (complete population). From these 6587 genes, I identified 348 in a different study and want to determine if these ones show some sort of systematic bias in terms of these distance values (i.e. have smaller or larger distance values than would be expected from the population)

Comment: So I randomly resample the total population with n=348 genes (without replacment), determine their mean value, and repeat this 1000 times.  When I do this, I get a distribution of mean values.  The mean value from the 'real' sample of 348 genes is smaller than all but 3 of the values generated by picking random samples. Hence, I conclude that it is unlikely that my 348 genes were selected by chance, since the probability of randomly picking 348 genes and getting a mean value this low (or lower) is about 3 in 1000.

Comment: Yes, that's a way of doing a randomization test of the mean. However, if you want a two-tailed test you should also consider the *other* tail. If you flip your sample mean the other side of the population mean (that is, consider a cut off of $\mu + (\mu-\bar{x})$), you can see how much of the sample lay at least that high for the upper tail. (Sometimes people just approximate it by doubling the p-value.)

Comment: OK thanks, is there another, better way of doing this?

Comment: "Better" kind of depends on your criteria. I think that randomization test is a great way to do it (though I'd use a larger sample, 10 times as big or more). Speaking for myself, to be honest, with those sample sizes, unless it was *really* badly skew or *really* heavy tailed (and in both those cases I'd question the value of using the mean anyway), I'd just do a one-sample t-test against the mean of the population (or a two-sample-t if I decided to treat it as a big sample) - the central limit theorem and Slutsky's theorem together should give you a nice normal distribution for the statistic.

Comment: OK, awesome. The randomization test gives me a p-value of ~0.006, the one-sample t-test against the mean of the population gives a p-value of 0.0042, and the two-sample-t gives a p-value of 0.0055.  These are all in good agreement and all fall below my threshold of p=0.01 so I can confidently conclude that the observed difference in means is not likely due to chance. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Before reading your list of 4 possibilities I was going to suggest drawing random samples, essentially what you describe in number 4.  The other options are probably reasonble given the sample size, but with modern computing power it just makes sense to do the random sampling that does not depend on other assumptions that may or may not be reasonable.

With the sampling you should compute the p-value by looking at the proportion of the sample means that are as extreeme or more extreeme than the one from the original data.  The distribution of the samples and the standard deviation don't matter, just how many are more extreeme (though with the sample size it is not surprising that the means follow close to a normal and this p-value will probably not differ by much from one based on normal calculations).

If you sample without replacement (recommended) then I would call this a permutation test rather than a bootstrap test, but it is in the grey area of overlap where either term could be justified.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the answer. I want to up-vote this answer, but I don't have high enough reputation. Can you explain the reasoning behind sampling without replacement in this case? Is this because if I were to reach into a bag of 6587 genes and randomly pull out 348, I would never pull out the same one twice?

Comment: @DevinKing, Sampling with replacement means that once you select one gene, you could possibly select it again.  Sampling without replacement means that you don't put the ones sampled back and cannot sample them again.  I would suggest sampling without replacement because that is a better representation of your original data (I assume that your original group would not have had duplicates, so the samples should not).  Sampling with replacement is used in standard bootstrapping where the sample size is the same, so without replacment would not vary.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Will do sampling without replacement for the randomization test.

Answer (score 0):

With a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) you can test whether two distributions are significantly different. The test is nonparametric, it doesn't matter which two distributions you compare.

Alternatively, you can use the Wilcoxon test. It does not require normally distributed data as the t-test.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm more interested in comparing the mean of the smaller sample with the mean of the total population.

Comment: But the Wilcoxon test is not a test of means (or even of medians).  The null for the Wilcoxon is actually the same as for KS, that the 2 distributions are the same.